# Optimizing BeautifulSoup (Python) code

Tags: python, optimization, beautifulsoup

I have code that uses the `BeautifulSoup` library for parsing, but it is very slow. The code is written in such a way that threads cannot be used. 
Can anyone help me with this?

I am using `BeautifulSoup` for parsing and than save into a DB. If I comment out the `save` statement, it still takes a long time, so there is no problem with the database.

```
def parse(self,text):                
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
    arr = soup.findAll('tbody')                

    for i in range(0,len(arr)-1):
        data=Data()
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(str(arr[i]))
        arr2 = soup2.findAll('td')

        c=0
        for j in arr2:                                       
            if str(j).find("<a href=") > 0:
                data.sourceURL = self.getAttributeValue(str(j),'<a href="')
            else:  
                if c == 2:
                    data.Hits=j.renderContents()

            #and few others...

            c = c+1

            data.save()
```

Any suggestions?

**Note:** I already ask this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711820/optimize-python-code-closed) but that was closed due to incomplete information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(str(arr[i]))
arr2 = soup2.findAll('td')
```

Don't do this: Just call `arr2 = arr[i].findAll('td')` instead.

---

This will also be slow:

```
if str(j).find("<a href=") > 0:
    data.sourceURL = self.getAttributeValue(str(j),'<a href="')
```

Assuming that getAttributeValue gives you the `href` attribute, use this instead:

```
a = j.find('a', href=True)       #find first <a> with href attribute
if a:
    data.sourceURL = a['href']
else:
    #....
```

---

In general, you shouldn't need to convert the BeautifulSoup object back into a string if all you want to do is parse it and extract values. Since the `find` and `findAll` methods give you back searchable objects, you can keep searching by invoking the `find`/`findAll`/etc. methods on the results.